# What to do when your character gets stabbed in the back by the whole party?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, group-dynamics

I'm fairly new to playing D&D.  I played a few games with my husband.

This is the first game I have played where he was not a player or the DM.

I am running a Paladin (of Mask the god of thieves) Rogue. I play her more like a Paladin and less like a Rogue.  She is chaotic neutral.   I have never stolen anything and yet the group treats me like a thief, my character's mission is to make sure thieves give Mask his share of the loot.

She falls in and out of love easily, so I started hitting on the neutral party mage who has played many games, and has proceded to punch me in the face until I was unconscious, fireballed me in battle.  Then I got prank thrown into the water by the rest of the group and the mage lightninged me while I was in the water not looking.  I went down.

The rest of the group who play neutral characters did nothing to the mage, just pulled me out of the water and stabilized me.  I came to.  I thought I was 4 and thought the mage was a possessed doll because he was so short.  He then proceded to chromatic orb me, so I used divine smite on him.  Unfortunately it did not perma kill him.

The group left me in the dungeon because I did not follow but at the time I did not like them.  When they came back for me they dragged me to a light temple (enemy of Mask)by my wrists to have me healed.  We are now in the inn at the town, will rest there this night.

The group does not let me have much loot and steal items I get from me.  I am the only one in the group that can heal and the only one who can pick a lock.  When I started playing I wanted to get alone with all the guys playing but now I fell like killing them off.

Is that acceptable in this situation, how could I do it?

Comment: Before anyone can answer this, what style of game are all of you playing: before you all began, was it agreed that Player- versus-Player was part of the game, or was it generally agreed to adventure as a team?  Without knowing that, we can't be sure if this is a problem between *players* (the real life people at the table) or between *characters.*   Please clarify.  Beyond that, a "should I do this" gets into an opinion based question which this site doesn't do as well as discussion forums.  I edited your post into readable form. Please revise if I made errors in meaning.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE.  Please take the [tour] and check out the [help] to see how this site works.  Our strength is in well focused questions that have "good, better, and best" answers.   Think through your question and try to identify "What problem am I trying to solve" and edit / revise your question accordingly.  Happy Gaming!  Oh, and speaking of gaming, what edition of what game are you playing?

Comment: Is the party evil? If not, then there must be something else going on wrt the RPG or social aspect of what they're doing. Is the group you're playing with a tight-knit group, and are you an "outsider"?

Comment: "I thought I was 4 and thought the mage was a possessed doll" - Was this inflicted by the party with a spell to specifically alter your mind, or did the DM whip this up? If it's the latter, it sounds like everyone's out to give your character a bad time. Unless this is a very one-sided story. -- Simple flirting doesn't merit assault. Has the mage (character or player) stressed a lack of interest aside from punching you? (Also, what kind of mage can punch people unconscious?)...

Comment: @Leriol *The rest of the group who play neutral characters* is in the middle of the question.

Comment: You might also want to specify the kind of relationship you have with other players (not characters). The way you depict it makes it look like they are just mean to you, but if that was the case I assume that you simply wouldn't play with them at all. In short, context is needed.

Answer (score -5):

Some groups consider it a bit rude to have your character do sexy things during a D&D game.  The reason is -- there are five or six people at the table, right?  But only two are talking about how their characters are doing sexy things, and the rest of them are sitting quietly and listening, and that's no fun for them.  If you want to have a scene where your character seduces someone else's character, a good way to do that might be to have the scene privately (not during the normal D&D game time) so that nobody's being forced to listen to the two of you.

So, it's possible that the group was mad at you because they wanted to roleplay that their characters were all fighting orcs, and you were distracting from that.

It's also possible that they're just jerks.  :)

It would be very difficult to have your character kill all their characters, because you're badly outnumbered and they have more experience at the game.  The best advice I can give you is to leave the game and join a different game instead.  It's not unusual to have to try multiple groups before you find one that fits your playstyle.